# Angular get futureSnapshot from router

Tags: angular, typescript

I´m working with angular 5, i create a authGuard to check if the user is login and if has the permission to get inside in the selected route, the user object has a list of permissions that i need to match with the route that he is trying to get access, but when i try to get the current `this.router.url` and `this.activedRouter.snapshot` has old data. When route changes, ActivatedRoute.snapshot has data from previous route, for example if i´m in the route `/home/library` and go to `/home/category` give me back `/home/library`

**authGuard**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CONFIG as CONST } from '../../app.config';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig, JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  private jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {

  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(`${CONST.SESSION}`)
        .toPromise()
        .then((res: any) => {
          const response: boolean = res.result;
          if (response) {
            const token = this.auth.getToken();
            const dt = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
            const activatedUrl = this.activatedRoute.snapshot;
            console.log(activatedUrl);
            // const string = route.charAt(1).toUpperCase() + route.slice(2);
            // const access = dt.PermissionClaim.indexOf(route) !== -1;
            resolve(response);
          }
        });
    });
  }
}
```

any idea how can i get the current route and the previous one, inside of the object `this.activatedRoute.root` there is property call `_futureSnapshot` that contains the futureRoute, but is a private property and i can not have access to it, is there any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a long search i finally  found the answer to the problem, to get the actually current route in the authGuar we need to use:

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    connsole.log(this.state.url)

}
```

whit `this.state.url` we get new route where the user is trying to get access, inside of the `authGuar`, and not the previous one.